# Why is LESSOPEN causing my command to hang?

Tags: shell, less, hang

I'm trying to read a filtered version of some files in `less` by using the `LESSOPEN` environment variable, but no matter how simple my preprocessor, the command hangs until I send it a `SIGINT` via Ctrl+C:

```
LESSOPEN='||cat' less foo bar
```

What am I doing wrong here? (Note that I can't just pass the input as a pipe, since I'm opening multiple files in separate buffers.)

Comment: Right now, I'm wondering if this might be a bug in Less, vis. current beta release notes like http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/news.520.html listing the change "Fix buffering bug when using stdin with a LESSOPEN pipe."

Comment: Well, building the latest beta didn't fix the issue, so if this *is* a bug, it isn't *that* bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the `%s`, without which `cat` didn't get a filename and is simply waiting for input from stdin:

```
LESSOPEN='||cat %s' less foo bar # works
LESSOPEN='||cat' less foo bar # hangs
```

The [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/less.1.html) says:

> To set    up an input preprocessor, set the LESSOPEN environment 
>   variable  to  a    command  line  which will invoke your input
>   preprocessor.  This command    line should include one occurrence of
>   the string "%s",  which  will  be    replaced  by  the  filename  when
>   the  input  preprocessor  command is    invoked.

Comment: @StuartP.Bentley nope, the command accepts *both* stdin and files. "the input pipe is used on standard input as well as other files." The phrase "input pipe" is misleading: what gets piped here is the output of the command in `LESSOPEN` to `less` (hence the pipe from `LESSOPEN` is the *input* to `less`). It doesn't mean that input files are piped *to* `LESSOPEN` in all cases.

Comment: Yeah, I deleted my initial comment a few seconds after I wrote it; as you said, the phrase is misleading (STDIN is only piped to the preprocessor, with a filename of `-`, when *the input to `less` itself* comes from STDIN, and even then, only when LESSOPEN has a hyphen at the beginning).

Comment: The good news is that the latest beta of Less includes an error message when an input pipe LESSOPEN is missing `%s`, so that might serve to tip others off to avoid this mistake in the future.

Comment: I've sent an email to bug-less@gnu.org pointing out the omission of this detail from the man page documentation.